# Why do I need to import both Hash from Crypto and PKCS1_OAEP from Crypto.Cipher for Hash.MD5 to work?

Tags: python, python-import, python-3.8

### With Both PKCS1_OAEP and Hash

```
from Crypto.Cipher import PKCS1_OAEP
from Crypto import Hash

Hash.MD5
```

That code works without issue.

### With Just Hash

```
from Crypto import Hash

Hash.MD5
```

That code gives me the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 3, in <module>
    Hash.MD5
AttributeError: module 'Crypto.Hash' has no attribute 'MD5'
```

### With Just PKCS1_OAEP

This doesn't work either:

```
from Crypto.Cipher import PKCS1_OAEP

Hash.MD5
```

That gives this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 3, in <module>
    Hash.MD5
NameError: name 'Hash' is not defined
```

I feel like it ought to work with just `from Crypto import Hash` but that's clearly not the case. Any ideas?

(I'm running Python 3.8.3)

Comment: I get the first error (`AttributeError `) when I run the first code block or the second.  For me, the line `from Crypto.Cipher import PKCS1_OAEP` makes no difference, and PyCharm shows it as unused. - I'm running Python 3.7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted this on https://discuss.python.org/t/why-do-i-need-to-import-both-hash-from-crypto-and-pkcs1-oaep-from-crypto-cipher-for-hash-md5-to-work/6840/3 and here's the response I got back:

---

I believe the problem is that Crypto.Hash is itself a package, not a
module. This means that there an MD5 module *inside* Crypto.Hash.

When you import Crypto.Hash, it runs the file
…/site-packages/Crypto/Hash/**init**.py. That will define various
names (possibly none - it is often an empty placeholder), but *won’t*
inherently import all the modules beside it.

So when you “import Crypto.Hash” you will get the name “Hash” containing
the things defined by the **init**.py file from the Hash package. That
does not imply there’s a Hash.MD5 name.

Conversely, “from Crypto.Hash import MD5” imports the name MD5 from the
Crypto.Hash *package* (collection of modules) i.e. the Crypto.Hash.MD5
module itself, and gives it the name “MD5” in your own namespace.

There’s an example of that form under “API principles” here:

```
https://www.pycryptodome.org/en/latest/src/hash/hash.html
```

which goes:

```
from Crypto.Hash import SHA256
```

I agree this is an unfortunate user experience (you being the user).